# DDMathParser: Parsing formulas which contain if statements

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing, nspredicate

I have started to implement `DDMathParser` in my current project and I use this framework   to calculate the results of formulas in combination with variables given in a dictionary (*variable substitution*).

Would it be possible to use something like `if` statements in the formulas, e.g. "`if ($a > 0) { $b / $c } else {$b * 1000}`?

I assume that `if` statements could be created in a similar way than new functions (as described in the [DDMathParser Wiki](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Adding-New-Functions)). If this would be the case, I would be glad if someone could show me how to do this.

Any ideas or hints on how to use `if` statements in `DDMathParser`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DDMathParser` author here...

This isn't really possible, but not for the reason you think.  `DDMathParser` can parse `if` just fine.  It's the curly braces it would have issues with.  You could maybe do:

```
if ($a > 0) ($b / $c) else ($b * 1000)
```

This would be parsed as:

```
if($a > 0) * ($b / $c) * else($b *1000)
```

Which is `NSLogged` as:

```
multiply(multiply(if(l_gt($a,0)),divide($b,$c)),else(multiply($b,1000)))
```

So, you could do it, but it would be a total pain to try and handle the scoping yourself.  I think it'd probably be easier to pre-parse the string into various parts:

```
if ($a > 0) => if(l_get($a, 0))
($b / $c) => divide($b, $c)
($b * 1000) => multiply($b, 1000)
```

And then handle that yourself.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, would that mean that I can use `if` statements in formulas but would have to replace the curley braces by something else? By the way `a`, `b` and `c` are variables which will be substituted. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexR you can use `if`, because DDMathParser would think it's the name of a function.  You'd then need to post-process the `DDExpression` to pull things out yourself.  `a`, `b`, and `c` are also seen as yet-to-be-resolved functions. (They'd be variables if they were `$a`, `$b`, and `$c`).

Comment: I came up with a simpler solution for my specific problem: I am using a variable (e.g. $`isInFuture` which I set to `0` if it is **false** or `1` if it is **true**. I can then write my formula as `$isInFuture * ($DDPS1 * Pc1) + (1 - $isInFuture) * ($DDPS2 * Pc2)` which evaluates either the first or the second statement. Is this `1 * $dummyVariable * x + (1 - $dummyVariable) * y` a viable strategy in your view?